# Why am I getting this error called java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, exception

I have written this code in Java on my 64 bit Linux system:

```
    class WrapperClass1
    {
       public static void main(String s [])
       {
            int noinput=s.length;
            System.out.println("Number of values entered is :- " + noinput);
            System.out.println( s[0] + "," + s[1] );
            int x = Integer.parseInt(s[0]);
            int y = Integer.parseInt(s[1]);
            int z = x + y;
            System.out.println(" Sum = " + z);
       }
    };
```

Now, when I try to compile it, it successfully compiles, but when I execute the program it shows me an exception called:

```
           Number of values entered is :- 0
           Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
           at WrapperClass1.main(WrapperClass1.java:7)
```

Comment: You are not passing any command line argument in your code while running it. So, you can't access `s[0]`.

Comment: how are you executing this?Are you passing any arguments while running?

Comment: Thanks friends, i passed the arguments on the command line itself which solved my problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input : String[]

to which method ? --> `main(String[] args)`

when to give ?    --> While we say `java <className> <input1> <input2> ...` to execute

when it throws `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` ? -->

Initial : String s[]

But before you initialise the variable(array), trying to access the index which is not available...

Solution : provide the inputs through the command(as these are command line args)

How to avoid error even if input is not given ? --> check the size of array,

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing any arguments which is causing this issue.

`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is

> Thrown to indicate that an array has been accessed with an illegal
>   index. The index is either negative or greater than or equal to the
>   size of the array.

In your case you are not passing while executing the program. So it's throwing exception while accessing `s[0]` or `s[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Your array s is empty so, when you try to pop items out of it like s[0] it will throw this exception because it doesn't have anything there.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using an *if* statement which checks if `noinput` is at least 2. Then you can use s[0] and s[1] freely without getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.